# Python Multithreaded Processing Clogging Up Memory

Tags: python, multithreading, memory, download

I am new to multithreaded processing in Python, but have been using the following code to run a multithreaded download, but after running this for several hours it eats up my memory over time and then stalls due to lack of free memory. I'm trying to figure out an alternative method that will allow me to run this process for several hours without having to worry about memory consumption:

```
def worker()
    while True:
        item = jq.get()
        download_stuff(item)
        jq.task_done()

input_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...]
num_threads = 8
q = Queue
jq = JoinableQueue()
for i in range(num_threads):
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for item in input_list:
    jq.put(item)

jq.join()
```